# Produce Multiple Sequence Alignments using Profile HMMs

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, hidden-markov-model, baum-welch, viterbi-algorithm

I have a few multiple sequence alignments and a few groups (let's say N) of unaligned sequences. I would like to **learn the emission and transition probabilities** from the multiple sequence alignments, to build with these distributions a *profile HMM* and then to produce with the Viterbi algorithm N multiple sequence alignments from the groups of unaligned sequences.

I have a known profile HMM structure, I have a Viterbi implementation but I am having trouble figuring out how to estimate emission distributions and transition distributions from the available multiple sequence alignments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of plugging my own package you can derive a profile HMM using the R package **aphid**. It isn't on CRAN yet but you can download it from github using the devtools package:

`devtools::install_github("shaunpwilkinson/aphid")`
`library(aphid)`

I recommend importing your sequences as a DNAbin object first using the **ape** package if possible, since **aphid** will recognize the residues as nucleotides and treat the ambiguities appropriately. Once you have your DNAbin object (say `x`) which can either be a matrix of aligned sequences or a list of non-aligned sequences, you can derive a profile HMM by running

`phmm <- derivePHMM(x)`

From there, your transition and emission probabilities can be returned by calling `phmm$A` and `phmm$E`, respectively.

Otherwise if you don't want to use R you could try either the HMMER (www.hmmer.org/) or SAM (https://compbio.soe.ucsc.edu/sam.html) package.

Comment: Maybe it was not clear from the question but I'm rather interested in a theoretical answer than a concrete implementation. As soon as I know what exactly I am searching I can decide upon using tools or implementing myself. Thanks, though. :)

Comment: You can't go past this book: Durbin R, Eddy SR, Krogh A, Mitchison G (1998) Biological sequence analysis: probabilistic models of proteins and nucleic acids. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, United Kingdom. Chapter 5.3 is all about deriving profile HMMs from multiple sequence alignments.